# Eloquent full name search not returning result

Tags: laravel, eloquent

here's my table data

| firstname | lastname |
| --- | --- |
| boy | 5 |
| boy | 55 |
| boy | 6 |
| boy | 7 |

here's my codes inside a search function

```
    $search = $request->search; 
    $users = \DB::table('users')
    ->where(function($query) use ($search){
        $query->where('firstname', 'like', '%'.$search.'%');
        $query->orWhere('lastname', 'like', '%'.$search.'%');
        $query->orWhereRaw(" concat(firstname, ' ', lastname) like '%?%' ", [$search]);
        $query->orWhere('email', 'like', '%'.$search.'%');
    })
    ->orderBy('firstname', 'asc')
    ->limit(20)
    ->get();
```

type in boy to press search, a bunch of matching result on firstname will return

type in 5 to press search, both the 5 and 55 row data will return

type in the full name "boy 5" to press search, no result return.

from my research, using orWhereRaw with concat and binding in this way should be getting result.
however, things doesn't work.

is there anything wrong ? btw, am running this in laravel 7.

Comment: this is not Eloquent btw

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
$query->orWhereRaw(" concat(firstname, ' ', lastname) like '%?%' ", [$search])
```

With

```
$query->orWhereRaw("concat(firstname, ' ', lastname) like ?", ['%'.$search.'%'])
```

Comment: @ineedhelp Sorry, typo. The `'` around `?` were not required. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

check out the below example and adjust your query function accordingly

```
//what is provided from search bar
$query = $request->input('query');

//db tbl that gets queried
$spa = spa::latest()->where('spa_name', 'LIKE', '%'.$query.'%')
                    ->orwhere('more_details','LIKE',  '%'.$query.'%')->get();
```